# Selenium webDriver actions without calling build()

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Actions without build():

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.doubleClick(element).perform();
```

This seems working fine without calling build() before perform(). What is the difference?

Comment: Did you read [the docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#perform--)? It literally states `perform()` is "A convenience method for performing the actions without calling build() first."

Answer (score 0):

From the source code in the Java bindings, `build()` and `perform()` are simply defined:

```
/**
   * Generates a composite action containing all actions so far, ready to be performed (and
   * resets the internal builder state, so subsequent calls to {@link #build()} will contain fresh
   * sequences).
   *
   * @return the composite action
   */
  public Action build() {
    Action toReturn = new BuiltAction(driver, new LinkedHashMap<>(sequences), action);
    action = new CompositeAction();
    sequences.clear();
    return toReturn;
  }

  /**
   * A convenience method for performing the actions without calling build() first.
   */
  public void perform() {
    build().perform();
  }
```

Fairly obviously, perform simply calls build so there is no functional difference between using `perform()` or `build().perform()`